# `async.series` not reaching second function

Tags: node.js

I have a sequence of modules I need to run in `node`, using `async`. I have `async.waterfall` nested within `async.series`, but am having trouble reaching the second function in the `async.series` method. The process ends after printing `"Processing images completed"`. This is running in `aws lambda`.

What am I doing wrong?

These is my module:

`S3resizer.rs`

```
    S3resizer.rs = function (imgName, bucketName, sizesObj, imageType, obj, cb) {

        var dir = "/tmp";

        async.series([
            function (next) {

                async.waterfall([
                    function (callback) {
                        S3get(bucketName, imgName, callback);
                    },
                    function (data, callback) {
                        async.each(sizesObj, function (sizesObj, mapNext) {
                            rs(data, imgName, dir, sizesObj, mapNext);
                        }, function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log("Error when resizing images, %s", err);
                                callback(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log("Processing images completed");
                                callback();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                ], function (err) {
                    console.log("Fetched and resized ok!");
                    next(null);
                });
            },

            function (next) {
                async.waterfall([
                    function (callback) {
                        console.log("reached readfile");
                        readDirFile(dir, callback);
                    }
                ], function (error, results) {
                    if(error) {
                        next(error);
                    } else {
                        next(null, results);
                    }
                });
            }
        ], function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err);
            } else {
                cb(null, results);
            }
        });
    };
```

The 'rs' module:

```
'use strict';

// dependencies
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });

var resizer = {};

resizer.resize = function (data, imgName, directory, sizesObj, callback) {

    if (data.hasOwnProperty('Body')) {
        data = data.Body;
    } else {
        data = data;
    }

    gm(data)
        .resize(sizesObj.width, sizesObj.height)
        .write(directory + "/" + sizesObj.name + "_" + imgName, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Error resizing image, %s", err.message);
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Wrote to %s directory, with size name %s and image name %s", directory, sizesObj.name, imgName);
            callback(null);
        });

};

module.exports = resizer;
```

Comment: why nest waterfall inside series .?

Comment: because I need to pass values between some of the methods

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right:

```
if (err) {
    console.log("Error when resizing images, %s", err);
} else {
    console.log("Processing images completed");
    callback;
}
```

First, you're not calling `callback` when an error occurs. And second, you're not actually *calling* the callback function as it's missing parentheses (i.e. `callback()`).

Comment: Changed that. Still not reaching the second function. I've also added the module I use in `S3resizer` as `rs`

Comment: What's `sizesObj`? `async.each()` iterates over arrays, not objects. Perhaps you should implement each step separately first to confirm the code works properly before hooking everything up using the various async functions.

Comment: `sizesObj` is an array of objects.